# Inline Javascript works, but doesn't work externally

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem. I have three text boxes, and the first two show first and last name. And I want the last textbox to contain both first and last.

**Here's the code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Textbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        First Name: <input id="fname" type="text" value="John"><br>
        Last Name: <input id="lname" type="text" value="Smith"><br>
        <input id="textbox" readonly>

        <button onclick="textbox.value=fname.value+' '+lname.value">press to see full name</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

This works fine, but when I try to use an external file, `testing.js` and switching `onclick="testFunction()"`, it doesn't work anymore.

**testing.js:**

```
function testFunction() {
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var last  = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var textb = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    textb     = first + " " + last;
}
```

Comment: you never do anything with textb. just assigning it.

Comment: Does the code in your post actually work? That seems unlikely, since you have a syntax error -- you can't put quotes for JavaScript inside of the same quotes for the HTML attribute.

Comment: Can you show us the script tag where you load the file containing testFunction() into the HTML?

Comment: yea the first block of code works

Comment: Then you changed it, because `onclick="textbox.value=fname.value+" "+lname.value">` won't work as written.

Comment: @ateich the script tag i used is: <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>

Comment: @sixfingeredman keep in mind the (unfortunate) fact that browsers treat elements with "id" values as global variables ...

Comment: @Pointy: True, but I was referring to the terminated string after the first `+`, which will create invalid JS.

Comment: @sixfingeredman ah yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/1vshky4s/

Ultimately your problem is that you are assigning the texb var the value of the text box, then overriding it with a concatenated string, then doing nothing at all with the results.

```
function testFunction()
{
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var textb = first + " " + last;

    document.getElementById("textbox").value = textb;
}
```

actually do something with the textb var and you should be good to go. Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

change your function to

```
function testFunction() {
    var first = document.getElementById("fname");
    var last = document.getElementById("lname");
    var textb = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textb.value = first.value + " " + last.value;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/f5by2pae/)

Answer (score -1):

Move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script
```

Into the `head` of page.
You try to bind function, than doesn't exist.
`script` will be loaded after dom.

p.s. Or use 'onload' event if `window`
p.s.s.

Here correct function:

```
function testFunction()
{
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var textb = document.getElementById("textbox"); //!

    textb.value = first + " " + last; // here was error

    }
```

Comment: Why would he move it to the head? It's fine where it is.

Comment: Yp, it's works without moving `script`.
An error was in testing.js.